# Arduino Look-alikes and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arduino, ubuntu-12.04, sensors

I had a general question about coding with Arduino Uno-R3 on Ubuntu. I'm thinking of getting one ebay. I do see a lot of similar ones (not arduino branded) but at lower price. I intend to use it by plugging it into ubuntu 12.04 and fix some simple sensors on it. Do these non-branded "arduino"-like boards work the same way that arduino does? For example if i write a simple flashing LED code from the arduino site and plug this generic one in, would it still work? Would the IDE/compiler tool (on ubuntu 12.04) work the same way? Basically I'm trying to see if anybody had any issues or if somethings don't work with the generic "arduino"-like boards.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Wouldnt that depend a lot on a particular board? I have an [Induino](http://www.simplelabs.co.in/catalog/induino-boards) with me and I have been able to used the arduino samples along with the IDE without any problems so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they will work exactly the same. The source code for the bootloader chip and the main mega328 is available, so the people who copy the designs just flash those on directly.

Just make sure the board you are getting is the correct version you want. Some clones may use the older FT232 chip to convert USB<->UART, where the newer boards have another atmega chip that can both act as a USB<->UART, and as a USB slave itself.

Comment: So, a listing like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/UNO-R3-Development-Board-MEGA328P-ATMEGA16U2-USB-Cable-Compatible-Arduino-New-/310675669282?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4855b68122) should work fine right?

Comment: @broccoli, yes I am buying it here, for example http://www.aliexpress.com/item/UNO-R3-MEGA328P-ATMEGA16U2-for-Arduino-Compatible-Free-Shipping-Dropshipping/850915954.html

Answer (score 0):

They do NOT work the same. For the same reasons that Arduino Boards do not work the same. Even Arduino has a lot of different variations of their branded boards.

However the non branded ones are usually compatible. The question is just to which of the Arduino variants. So in the end it all boils down to proper setup of the corresponding branded Arduino Board.

Some of the differences for both Arduino and the clones:

1) Varying processor
  --> affects number of pins
  --> affects size of memory (flash, sram and eeprom)
  --> affects low level port adresses
  --> affects number of hardware counter
  --> affects number and variety of hardware support for different interfaces
  --> affects programmer options / support
2) Varying interface for the host computer
  --> serial, or USB - serial bridge, native USB
    --> affects if you need an external USB - serial converter
    --> affects maximum possible serial communication speed
    --> affects possibility to act as a native USB device
3) Varying clock options
  --> affects computational power
  --> affects power consumption (overall effect is negligible though)
  --> affects clock stability and precission 
    --> crystals are more precise and stable than resonators
      --> attention: if this is important to you: the newer Arduinos have resonators for the main processor, you might want to consider a dedicated RTC clock anyway
4) Varying goodies
  --> on board RTC, accelerometer, WLAN, LED bar, ...
5) Build quality
  --> Original Arduinos are usually OK
  --> very cheap clones sometimes require some rework (align pins, resolder some pins)
  --> there are clones that are actually better than Arduino and still cheaper

However notice that it is very easy to roll your own board once you understand the hardware of Arduino. If you do not need a precise clock you can go for the integrated RC Oscillator. Then an Arduino clone is nothing but the bare processor plus one capacitor. The only thing you need in addition is an ISP programmer.